# Поиск палиндрома максимальной длины

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, fstream

> Создать файл из N целых чисел. Найти отрезок массива максимальной 
>   длины, в котором первое число равно последнему, второе -
>   предпоследнему и т.д. Напечатать длину этого отрезка и весь файл.

Несколько дней просидел, ушёл чуть дальше объявления, нужна помощь хотя бы с алгоритмом

Comment: То, что вам надо найти - палиндром, только не на строке, как массиве символов, а на массиве чисел. Разница не принципиальная. Рекомендую статью https://habr.com/ru/post/276195/

Answer (score 0):

Сначала напишите функцию, которая проверяет для двух указателей верность условия задачи.

```
bool check(const int* first, const int* last)
{
    while (first != last) {
        if (*first++ != *last--)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Потом читайте из файла все числа в массив(в контейнер), размер которого известен(равен N).    `int arr[N];` И вам нужна максимальная длина такого отрезка. Сначала инициализируйте его наименьшим значением   `unsigned max_langth = 1;` А потом проверьте вохвращает ли функция истину для указателей на начало и конец отрезка. Если да, то разность этих указателей выдаст длину отрезка и вы его сравните:

```
if(max_langth < dist)
    max_langth = dist;
```

Выполните это для всех возможных отрезков массива(в циклах). В итоге получите `max_langth` с нужным значением

Comment: Цикл не останавливается вовремя, например, на массиве из двух одинаковых чисел.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy,  ошибка может быть и есть(нужно просто исправить условия). так как это не решение, а  помощь найти подход к решению. Из за этого не обращено внимание на детали.